Can someone not be declared dead after being missing, for an indefinite time?
This is about a fictional story where a man was a majority owner of a corporation; he, his wife, and their son, an only child, vanished on a foreign trip; while the man and his wife had died, their son returned many years later, such that he could not have appealed the settlement of their estates if they had been declared dead after seven years; the corporation was controlled by the children of the minority owner; and at the end of the story, the son had regained ownership and control of the company.
Obviously the most obvious reason is that the writers didn't bother to consider the law, but is it possible that they simply didn't go to court to have the man, his wife, and his son declared dead, and let the situation go on?
From what I can glean online, someone actually has to go to court to have a person missing for seven years declared dead.  Would it be feasible to just not do it?  Would there be any trouble with corporate law because the owner was not available for over a decade that would force them to go to court?

It's not about anything except whether it's feasible for a minority owner to avoid having the other owner declared dead.  Shortening the time would not affect it.  Neither would questions about debts, and since the minority owner is still running it, the company does not need to be wound down.  Etc.

It would be feasible for them not to be declared dead (and incidentally, the rules for doing so are a matter of state law and vary from one state to another). No one is obligated to bring a proceeding to have someone declared dead and courts don't pro-actively adjudicate issues that aren't brought before them.
Realistically, some sort of court action would be necessary for the missing family's assets to be managed (unless there were powers of attorney or trusts with active trustees in place to do so), but this wouldn't necessarily require a declaration of death. The same process would apply if they were known to be alive but incapable of managing their affairs or communicating with the outside world in any detail, for example, in a North Korean prison.

If they had made arrangements for the management before the trip, without a time limit, would that do it?

@Mary This would probably be sufficient until someone pushed to have them declared dead, and there might be no one else with standing to do so.

I am just looking at pensions, and at least one pension will require a declaration once a year that I'm still alive to pay for another year. I wonder how this combines with being declared dead or not.

@gnasher729 A pension company would probably have standing to bring a proceeding to have someone declared dead.

@gnasher729 Fortunately for this theory, the adults are too young for pensions yet in the story.  Heirs would probably have standing, but perhaps are unaware -- his estranged brother's children, or the charity that was designated in case his wife and children predeceased him.
